# Non blocking pipe descriptor flag value interpretation

Tags: c, fcntl

I am trying to code a nonblocking pipe, my code is as follow

```
int fd = open(fifo_path, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK );
int flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
printf("flag is %d \n", flag);
```

The flag printout is 34816 in decimal (or 8800 in hex). I have checked the fcntl-Linux.h, I have found the value should be 04000 in hex (O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK. is 0 | 04000)

Is my calculation rite? Just trying to check the numbers

Thanks
Regards

Comment: The *file status flags* obtained via `fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)` are related to, but not identical with, the `flags` argument to `open()`.  See [the `open()` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).  But with that said, I'm not prepared to explain the specific flag values you report.  I would guess that you're getting some default status flags associated with the file type, which I infer is a fifo.

Comment: Check the POSIX specifications for [`fcntl()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) and the header [`<fcntl.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html).  The `F_GETFL` returns two sets of values: the file status flags and the file access modes.  The header defines which flags are status flags  (`O_APPEND`, `O_DSYNC`, `O_NONBLOCK`, `O_RSYNC`, `O_SYNC`), and which are access modes (`O_EXEC`, `O_RDONLY`, `O_RDWR`, `O_SEARCH`, `O_WRONLY`) plus `O_ACCMODE` to separate the access mode(s) from the status flags.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  ..thanks for your help...it seems that the value of fcntl header is written in octets instead of hex..then the value make sense

Answer (score -1):

Using the information from the POSIX specifications of [`fcntl()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) and [`<fcntl.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html), you might come up with this code.  It uses some error reporting code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

```
/* SO 7574-0162 */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* fcntl() */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* unlink() */
#include <sys/stat.h>   /* mkfifo() */
#include "stderr.h"     /* err_setarg0(), err_syserr() */

int main(void)
{
    err_setarg0("fcntl13");
    const char fifo_path[] = "tmp.fifo";

    if (mkfifo(fifo_path, 0666) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to create FIFO %s: ", fifo_path);

    int fd = open(fifo_path, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to open FIFO %s: ", fifo_path);
    int flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flag < 0)
        err_syserr("fcntl() failed: ");

    printf("flag = %6d = 0x%.4X (%#.6o)\n", flag, flag, flag);

    int accmode = flag & O_ACCMODE;
    if (accmode == O_EXEC)
        printf("mode => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_EXEC", O_EXEC);
    if (accmode == O_RDONLY)
        printf("mode => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_RDONLY", O_RDONLY);
    if (accmode == O_RDWR)
        printf("mode => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_RDWR", O_RDWR);
    if (accmode == O_SEARCH)
        printf("mode => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_SEARCH", O_SEARCH);
    if (accmode == O_WRONLY)
        printf("mode => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_WRONLY", O_WRONLY);

    if (flag & O_APPEND)
        printf("flag => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_APPEND", O_APPEND);
    if (flag & O_DSYNC)
        printf("flag => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_DSYNC", O_DSYNC);
    if (flag & O_NONBLOCK)
        printf("flag => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_NONBLOCK", O_NONBLOCK);
#ifdef O_RSYNC      /* Not present on macOS Ventura 13.2.1 */
    if (flag & O_RSYNC)
        printf("flag => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_RSYNC", O_RSYNC);
#endif
    if (flag & O_SYNC)
        printf("flag => %-10s (0x%.4X)\n", "O_SYNC", O_SYNC);

    /* There's nothing you can do if the close fails */
    /* The code could report if it fails to unlink the FIFO, but ... */
    close(fd);
    unlink(fifo_path);
    return 0;
}
```

When run on a MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura 13.2.1, I get the output:

```
flag =      4 = 0x0004 (000004)
mode => O_RDONLY   (0x0000)
flag => O_NONBLOCK (0x0004)
```

Clearly, the code could/should be revised to take a file type and file name as an argument, a value for the open mode, and a value for the file permissions.  It might be commanded to create the file (like it creates the temporary FIFO), but would not create the file by default, and so on — the design requires a bit of thought, especially if the open modes and permissions are to be strings rather than just numbers.